# References (in bibtex) did not appear in beamer?

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I have this problem: it seems that beamer did not read the bibtex file. Below is the syntax that I am using:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{natbib} %citep and citet
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\subsubsection*{\bibname}} % to avoid References creates new section/subsection in header
\bibpunct[:]{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{,}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}
\def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{reff.bib} % file name of the bibtex
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use four spaces at the beginning of a line tho mark the line as code (or highlight a block of code and use the `101010`-button). Please also include newlines at the appropriate places to make the code readable.

Comment: which beginning of a line did you mean?

Comment: Well, you've not got any citations so you won't get any bibliography, `beamer` or not.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add

```
\nocite{*}
```

in your document for testing.

Then you should get a bibliography, which includes your complete bib file items. In a real beamer document you can use `\cite` commands or more specific forms of `\nocite` instead, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert the bibliography without the .bib extension, therefore as

```
\bibliography{reff} % file name of the bibtex
```

Comment: Sometimes? ....